Teams Bot App with SSO on K8S Experiences Multiple Responses with HPA Scaling Beyond Two Pods
We have developed a bot App by referencing the example of the bot app with SSO Enabled from the teams toolkit sample and deployed it to our on-premise K8S, making it publicly accessible at the service endpoint (https://testdomain.com/service/api/messages). The manifest for this teams bot app has also been uploaded to our organization's apps.
Teams toolkit SSO Bot Sample
At the same time, we have also created an Azure Bot app resource in Azure and set the message endpoint to point to our service endpoint on K8s
 Azure Bot app  message endpoint
Currently, we have encountered an issue where if the HPA on K8s is set with more than two Pods, there is a situation where multiple responses are returned for a single input
multiple responses are returned for a single input
HPA Settings in deployment yaml file
When the HPA is set with only one Pod, it operates normally .
Is there a best practice for HPA settings(we need more than two pods) when deploying with the bot framework (to my knowledge, the teams toolkit bot is based on the bot framework) to avoid this issue?

The sample uses a memory storage to deduplicate signin requests from Teams clients. You need a distributed storage in K8S. Refer to: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/issues/1266#issuecomment-2079027497
